# Tumblr like button not working for my tumblr blog

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, tumblr

Tumblr like button is not working for my Tumblr blog, the button's color change after clicking but after refreshing the page no updates happen

URL: http://cs.jumzler.com/

HTML code: `

```
{block:Posts}<p align="right"><div class="my-like" data-reblog="{ReblogURL}" data-id="{PostID}" title="Like"></div></p>{/block:Posts}
```

CSS:

```
    <style>
.my-like {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAARCAYAAAA/mJfHAAABH0lEQVQ4y62T30vCUBiGv/9YuhBLkCA08FdogRFFYFEUhhZNCCQoSESiIOii68pl5qV6s8Eb7+SMHXNs6S7ejZ3zvA+ccT4BICofvS88dJ7w8vqG8WQC754K17lPjrx3z3l8D4YoVaqIrWbcJNbzaHefNZjfXPdy5b0jsO/IRqMxUpmSBnhz2bx1QL79GPbpEePmzhdSyW8fBDL0SK68HwiGCT2S3NiKREaPzP7QRRNPZSHpwm4kMnqkYbQikdEjZv8HK2ubS4nY75mD6WU8qzeXkrHvToBlWSjuHC4kYo99V8bwBnM0/iMiz542myq2bSPskcmR/zPos7lvP8Lv/nGd+/N6c2Xq2KcXhiY6qV1rxwotU3n/NHF8fgW+g9hfsHJlJUYljcgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) !important;
    height:17px;
    width:19px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.my-liked, .my-like:hover {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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) !important;
    height:17px;
    width:19px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
```

JS:

```
    <script>
window.onload = function () {
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<iframe id="my-like-frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>' );
document.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
    var myLike = event.target;
    if( myLike.className.indexOf( 'my-like' ) > -1 ) {
        var frame = document.getElementById( 'my-like-frame' ),
            liked = ( myLike.className == 'my-liked' ),
            command = liked ? 'unlike' : 'like',
            reblog = myLike.getAttribute( 'data-reblog' ),
            id = myLike.getAttribute( 'data-id' ),
            oauth = reblog.slice( -8 );
        frame.src = 'http://www.tumblr.com/' + command + '/' + oauth + '?id=' + id;
        liked ? myLike.className = 'my-like' : myLike.className = 'my-liked';
    };
}, false );
};
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `Refused to display 'https://www.tumblr.com/like/gr5tXxxU?id=120690935349' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.` You can no longer use `iframes` to simulate `likes`

Comment: I would suggest this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21715659/2312574 :D