# change default tumblr like and reblog button

Tags: html, tumblr, tumblr-themes

Is it possible to change the tumblr default like/reblog buttons and insert an img? I'm trying to change my like button to http://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m7wvvwuZdH1r17mw1.png
(excuse the link. I can't post images yet because of reputation/I'm a newbie.)

.

here is what my like/reblog button code looks like

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div class="buttoned">{LikeButton size="14" color="black"}</div>
    <div class="buttoned">{ReblogButton size="14" color="black"}</div>
```

and

```
/* BUTTONS */

#buttons {
width: 18px;
height: auto;
position:absolute;
margin: -5px 0 0 540px;
}

.buttoned {
width:14px;
height:14px;
padding: 2px;
margin: 0 auto 4px auto;
background-color: {color:buttons};
border: 1px solid {color:buttons};
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.buttoned img {
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

Here is the blog I am trying to change it on. http://kobisart.tumblr.com/
As you can see I'm trying on the like button. It allowed me to put the img but it won't let me use it as the like button

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customise Tumblr's \*new\* Like Button iFrame {LikeButton}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708662/customise-tumblrs-new-like-button-iframe-likebutton)

Answer (score 1):

A reblog button can be achieved with the undocumented `{ReblogURL}`.

```
<a href="{ReblogURL}"><img src="img.png"></a>
```

An alternate like button can be achieved via [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21715659/4944981).