# Tumblr theme like-button not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

Using default theme Optica with a bit custom CSS.
I recently noticed that the like-button next to posts is not working.
It points to an iframe but nothing happens when clicked.

Alarmed, I reverted back to plain Optica without changes, cleared caches and reloaded the blog, but like-button still not working.

Developer tools of the browser says it cannot connect tumblr.com server (tumblr.com/svc/like:1) giving error 403.

Any solutions or where or how to start solving this issue?

Comment: I looked quickly and found no existing issue on their Github... But there actually are some ["outage"](http://downdetector.com/status/tumblr/map/)... Very few...

Comment: Hmm I dunno if that could be the case. I read that browsers recently did some changes to how iframes are handled, so I'm suspecting if it could be an issue...

Comment: This might be a new question though I add it here for now: IS there somewhere a detailed guide to replace tumblr like & reblog buttons...?

Comment: Maybe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025563/change-default-tumblr-like-and-reblog-button

Comment: I really want to solve this.. Those guides aren't too helpful to replace like-button... I'm not sure where to put the code of HTML(!) :/ That CSS I can manage though.