# Tumblr theme like button in text

Tags: button, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I have been trying and researching for days but I could not figure out how to make Tumblr Theme Like button in text. This `{LikeButton}` just adds that heart icon which doesn't go well with anything. Instead, I need to show it as "Like" in text.

Appreciate helps a lot! Thanks

Comment: I am sure this is possible, but could you share some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customise Tumblr's \*new\* Like Button iFrame {LikeButton}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708662/customise-tumblrs-new-like-button-iframe-likebutton)