# Custom like button liked state didn't work

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I used the following code from this article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708662/customise-tumblrs-new-like-button-iframe-likebutton)

Despite looking right and usable on my blog, it didn't show the liked state as described in the article.

My blog: https://14test.tumblr.com

Here is the code:
HTML

```
<center><div class="custom-like-button">
  {LikeButton}
  <span class="our_toggle">
  <div class="like_button">
  </div>
  <span class="our_button">
    &hearts;
  </span>
</div></center>
```

CSS

```
        .custom-like-button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.like_button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
.like_button iframe {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
.our_button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.like_button:hover + .our_button {
  color: red;
}
.like_button.liked + .our_button {
  background: white;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
<center><div class="custom-like-button">
  {LikeButton}
  <span class="our_toggle">
  <div class="like_button">
  </div>
  <span class="our_button">
    &hearts;
  </span>
</div></center>
```

To this:

```
<center>
   <div class="custom-like-button">
   {LikeButton}
       <span class="our_button">
          &hearts;
       </span>
   </div>
</center>
```

The issue is that your css for your current selector is trying to use the [Adjacent Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) but this will not work because your markup is nested inside another element.

Additionally you have a `<div class="like_button"></div>` block in your markup, but the same selector/classname is generated by Tumblr inside the `{LikeButton}` and I think that is causing an issue binding to the click event.

I tested it in the browser and got it to work, but you will need to update this to make sure it works for you.

Comment: OK just saw your new post. Please vote on this, or accept it, if it worked for you.

Comment: I tried to but it said I need at least 15 reputations to cast one :( Anyway I can upvote your solution?

Comment: OK, we can see if we can work on that :) No worries.